# Laravel: collect() helper - set type of collection

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-collection

If I do this:

```
$obj = factory(Object::class)->make();

collect($obj);
```

I am returned a collection of type:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection
```

Laravel also lets you define your own collections with their specific methods.  In the model, you do:

```
public function newCollection(array $models = [])
{
    return new CustomCollection($models);
}
```

and you would make your `CustomCollection`, starting like this, in the file CustomCollection.php:

```
class CustomCollection extends Collection
{
```

I'm wondering how I can return a collection of type:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
```

or, in the case of creating my own custom collection, how could I return a collection of type:

```
App\Models\CustomCollection
```

I'd like to do this with the `collect()` helper or any other way where I don't access the database for purposes of writing PHPUnit tests.

==========

EDIT: I'm using `factory(Object::class)->make()` to spoof Eloquent objects which I was trying to roll into collections.

If you just do `factory(Object::class, 1)->make()` instead, the factory rolls the single instance of `Object::class` into an Eloquent collection for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `collect()` helper just creates a new instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

```
function collect($value = null)
{
    return new Collection($value);
}
```

You can do the same with any collection.

**Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection**

```
$collection = new Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection($value);
```

**App\Models\CustomCollection**

```
$collection = new \App\Models\CustomCollection($value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using:

```
$obj = factory(Object::class)->make();
```

to spoof Eloquent objects, if you just do this instead:

```
$collection = factory(Object::class, 1)->make()
```

The `factory()` rolls the single instance of `Object::class` into an Eloquent collection for you.  The `1` is the number of objects in the collection produced, so you can change that to a `2` if you want 2 objects, etc.